# What does "%%" mean in Java?

Tags: java, printing, formatter

I've inherited some code that I'm trying to modify, and I've see the following syntax in a number pf places.

```
int titleRecEnd        = inputLine.indexOf("%%headerEnd");  
...
int fileNameStart      = inputLine.indexOf("%%File: ")+8;
int fileNameEnd        = inputLine.indexOf("%%FilenameEnd");
```

I've reviewed [this related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030561/what-does-the-mean-in-java) but can;t find an exact match for the dual `%` either as an answer or in the javadoc associated with the answer. I understand that it has to do with print formattimg, but I can't seem to find syntactical information about `%%` instead of, `%`.

What do these veriable declarations do--or what are they supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just used as a literal string? Does the textfile contain '%%headerEnd'? The `%.3f` from your link isn't the same as this: it means there will be a floating punt with 3 digit accuracy and is used for formatting output.

Comment: This looks more like a custom replacing mechanism or a external library that interprets `%%` in a special way.

Comment: The texfile does not contain any occurences of `%%`. The string `File:` appears in the file, but `FilenameEnd:` and `headerEnd` are not defined anywhere as variable names, nor do they appear as literal Strings.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a PostScript or PDF file?

Comment: @splungebob - Nope, straight up text. I even scrubbed the file to change all the `[^A-Z0-9]` to underscore `_` to ensure I didn't run into any oddness with special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%% means % character for java.util.Formatter pattern. Since % denotes the beginning of format specifier %% is used to escape % char.

```
System.out.println("%%");
```

prints

```
%
```

For String.indexOf % or %% have no special meaning.

Comment: I think you made a mistake. "%%" in print or println prints %%. But if you use %% in the formatting string of printf however, %% prints %.

Comment: Same thing in the C language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that a double percent is used to create a literal '%', i.e. the first percent sign escapes the second.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

How you use it there, it appears to simply be part of the string literal.  E.g. it might be used to parse a file like this:

```
%%headerStartSomeHeader%%headerEnd
%%File: image.png%%FilenameEnd
```

In the context of [string formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), `%` is a special character used to denote various things; `%%` resolves to a single literal `%` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I am certain it is simply a convention to find pieces of text in a larger string, as a percent normally does not appear double. Some kind of **templating**. So one can find "keywords" like `%%File`.

```
String fileName = inputLine.substring(fileNameStart, fileNameEnd);
```